# jQuery - Own Plugin / function bind on new ( generated ) objects

Tags: jquery

I'm a jQuery beginner and I want to create a colorpicker Plugin.
What I've done yet is working fine but there's a problem.

For all static content in my Webpage, the Plugin works fine with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.col').colorPicker();
});
```

But if there are new via jQuery generated ".col" objectes too, i've to run "$('.col').colorPicker()" again, to bind an ColorPicker object on these items.

Is there any possibility to do this on the fly with the Plugin itself and without running the "$.colorPicker()" command?

some time ago i remember i did this with "this['live']('click', fn)" but this isn't working any longer..

---

Edit:

I haven't the code of the plugin with me now, but I can give you an other example with the base structure of my plugin..

```
(function ($) {

    function valueReplacer(element) {
        this.element = element;
    } 

    valueReplacer.prototype = {
        // set a new value
        setValue : function() {
            this.element.val('new value');
        }
    }

    // call method of colorPicker instance
    function setValue() {
        $.data(this, "colorPicker").setValue();
    }

    $.fn.valueReplacer = function() {

        return this.each(function() {
            // prevent multiple instances
            if(!$.data(this, "valueReplacer")) {
                $.data(this, "valueReplacer", new valueReplacer($(this)));
            }   
        }); 

    }
})(jQuery);
```

.. everything this example plugin should do now, is to set the value of an input 
( `$(input).valueReplacer()` ) to "new value" when clicking on it..

but where and how should I set the `.on`, so that the `setValue()` method is called when an element, instantiated with the valueReplacer object is clicked?

Comment: There are no methods to auto run code when a new element becomes available that is cross-browser and efficient. There has to be some form of an event, such as an ajax success callback.

Comment: so.. there is no way to say "every element with the class `xyz` sould become an instance of the jQuery Plugin - weather if it is created by loading the page itself or added it dynamically later" ?

Comment: No, there is a way, it just isn't very efficient. You could use a setInterval, or a self calling function with a setTimeout. However that's incredibly inefficient considering the alternative (having a refresh method that can be used to make the plugin look for new elements when elements are added.)

Answer (score 0):

From the version 1.7 .live() is deprecated. What jQuery version are you using?

Try using jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method if you want to attach a listener on an element that will be dynamically added.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of jQuery.
But how can I use .on to bind methods of my Plugin Class on the dynamically generated items?

Answer (score 0):

In **modern browsers**, you could use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) object to observe `DOM` changes and detect if new elements that you are interested in have been added to the `DOM`.

Another alternative would be to listen to events directly on the `document` instead of each individual `.col` elements. You can pass a `selector` as as second argument to the jQuery `on` function that will automatically filter the events to make sure your handler is only called when a `.col` element is clicked. By doing this, you will handle clicks of `.col` elements added after your plugin has been initialized without the need of re-initializing it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.col', function () {
    //console.log('.col clicked!');
});
```

For the plugin you added, I had an idea on how you could structure things up using the above approach. Check a look at that fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Xy6WB/3/

```
(function ($) {
    var initialized = false,
        methods = {
            setValue: function (value) {
                this.innerHTML = value;
            }
        },
        slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    $.fn.valueReplacer = function(method) {
        var args = slice.call(arguments, 1);

        if (!initialized) {
            //when a plugin element is clicked, invoke the function in the
            //context of that element
            $(document).on('click', '.value-replacer-plugin', function (e) {
                methods.setValue.call(this, 'another value');
            });
        }

        //the plugin will automatically handle any element with
        //the value-replacer-plugin class, so here just add the class
        //to the element
        if (this.length) {
            this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass('value-replacer-plugin');

                if (method) {
                    methods[method].apply(this, args);
                }
            });
        }

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yeah.. but where and how should i do this, to affect all of the ( in the added example ) valueReplacer objects - even if there are more than one class like .col is instanciated with the valueReplacer Plugin Object?

Answer (score 0):

As marko mentioned live() can now be written $(document).on('action', 'selector', callback)

This mean if you click on the document, and the place you clicked matches the selector, then the callback is fired. Check jQuery on() docs for more info.